# I want to use RTL, but not through all of my components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js, right-to-left, direction

I want to use RTL for some of my components in Nextjs. I also use material-ui. Unfortunately when I change direction in **_documents.js** with `<HTML dir="rtl">`, the direction of all of my components will change. material-ui's direction in `createMuiTheme()` doesn't affect direction at all.

Some of the components (like arrows) must not change based on direction. What should I do in order to keep them safe from changing direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Material Ui `createMuiTheme` get direction as an option itself
<sub>I also remember that it respect the direction of body tag</sub>

So for changing the direction of some part of your component, you have 3 ways as I know.

1. Change direction option in material `createMuiTheme`

> It could be handle via your theme provider component for example

2. Use other instance of material Theme provider around your rtl components
   [Theme nesting](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#theme-nesting)
3. Put dir="rtl" on native DOM tags these will affect all lower subtree styles if you want e.g. flex-box direction and ...

**for example**

```js
const ARABIC_PATTERN = /[\u0600-\u06FF]/
const getDirection = text => (ARABIC_PATTERN.test(text) ? 'rtl' : 'ltr')


<div dir={getDirection('what you want to test')}>
  <Components />
</div>
```

Comment: thank you Amirhossein. I already tried your way, but unfortunately it did not work for me. There is another way to this problem which @GBra proposed below your answer. I tried it and it worked.

Comment: the only important thing is that your problem is now solved :), I somehow wrote that answer for prosperity

Answer (score 1):

Hacky suggestion. It's probably not the best answer, but it might be handy/decent if you need to just "reset" the position of 1-2 elements.

First invert everything like your are doing, then put a CSS class on the elements that shall not be "inverted":

```
.not-rtl-inteverted {
   transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

This way, you are basically inverting everything, and then inverting once again the elements with the class above.

```css
section {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
}


div {
background: green;
padding: 20px;
margin: 0 10px;
flex-basis: 33%;
}


.rtl {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

```html
<section>

<div>
<p>No RTL</p>
</div>


<div>
<p>Yes RTL</p>
</div>


<div>
<p>Yes RTL - but reset it on the 2nd line (by applying the same CSS class again)</p>
</div>

</section>



<section>

<div>
<p>text 1</p>
<p>text 2</p>
</div>


<div class="rtl">
<p>text 1</p>
<p>text 2</p>
</div>


<div class="rtl">
<p>text 1</p>
<p class="rtl">text 2</p>
</div>

</section>
```

In the example, by using twice the same class (once in the parent and once again the children that doesn't need to be rtl'd, we have this reset effect).

Again, might be handy for very simple use cases. I won't suggest this as a general solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. 
It helped a lot.